# $I=[a,b]$, $f:I→\mathbb{R}$ continuous on $I$ s.t. $\forall x∈I,\ \exists y∈I$ s.t. $|f(y)|≤\frac{1}{2}|f(x)|$. Prove $\exists c∈I$ s.t. $f(c)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I=[a,b]$, and $f:I→\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $I$ such that $\forall x∈I,\ \exists y∈I$ such that $|f(y)|≤\frac{1}{2}|f(x)|$. Prove $\exists c∈I$ such that $f(c)=0$

What I tried to do is constructing a sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $|f(x_{n+1})|≤\frac{1}{2}|f(x_{n})|≤......≤(\frac{1}{2})^{n}|f(x_{1})|$, then $lim_{n→\infty}f(x_{n})=0$, but how can I prove there exists $c∈I$ and $f(c)=0$?

Does anyone could help me? Thanks

Comment: I think you're almost there.  Since $\{x_n\}\subseteq [a,b]$, there is a convergent subsequence.  Then use continuity.

Comment: I got it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't you already? You proved

$$|f(x_{n+1})|\le\left(\frac12\right)^n|f(x_1)|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\implies $$

using Bolzano-Weierstrass prove the exists a subsequence of $\;\{x_n\}\;$ that converges to $\;c\in [a,b]\;$ (why?) and you're done.

Comment: I got it, how stupid I am, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I was having problems with this sum, so thanks for the question and the solution to you both! :) I have one silly doubt though: i continuity of $f$ not necessary here, since we haven't used it anywhere in the proof.....

Comment: Never mind, I think I get it. $lim(x_k)=c \Rightarrow lim(f(x_k)=f(c)$ by continuity. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

Note that $I$ is compact and $x \mapsto |f(x)|$ is continuous.
Let $m = \min_{x \in I} |f(x)|$. let $x_m \in I$ be such that $|f(x_m)| = m$.

Then we have $m=0$. If not, we have $m>0$ and some $y \in I$ such that
$|f(y)| \le {1 \over 2} m$, which is a contradiction.

Hence $f(x_m) = 0$.